# how to set values to Set<Object> through setter methods

Tags: java, collections

I want to set values to Set object through setter methods.

```
     @Override
    public User mapRow(final ResultSet resultSet, final int rownumber)
                            throws SQLException {

     Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();

     // tried with like this but it is not possible

     userRoles.add(userRoles.setUserId("ID"));

     return null;
    }
```

how can i set those values to set object.

Comment: read this again: `userRoles.add(userRoles.setUserId("ID"));` you must put get. And why you want to add one item in the same list?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear!. You wanted to add the id to specific UserRole   Object(s)  which is present in Set collection..??? or how you wahted to do..?

what ever you do your Set is a genaric of UserRole Object so you can add only object of UserRole not any other type!.

Hear your trying to set other than UserRole Object (In your case it may be String/Integer) so usaully setter method is void means return nothing!!!

```
userRoles.add(userRoles.setUserId("ID"));
```

So first heave the UserRole object ready by setting ID like

```
UserRole role = new UserRole();

// Set what ever the value you want 

role.setId("ID");
```

Then do as bellow

```
Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();

     // tried with like this but it is not possible

     userRoles.add(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Set with a generic type of UserRole:

But then you are trying to add

```
userRoles.add(userRoles.add(...
```

which tries to add a **boolean** for the outer call!

Can't work!

You see, [Set.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) takes an "E" input and gives back boolean. So you can't add(add())!

And then: your method is supposed to return an object of type *User*; but then you create a `Set<UserRole>` ... which you also want to return.

So long story short: you should have a closer look into the java basics first. It seems that you really do not know what you are doing.